# Convert a react class component to react hooks component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

I want to convert this react class component into a react hooks component.
I converted most of the code and now I need help to convert the part of code that is between the render and the return functions.

Here is the class component:

```
class LoginGoogle extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        data: {},
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`/api/auth/google/callback${this.props.location.search}`, { headers: new Headers({ accept: 'application/json' }) })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
            })
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ loading: false, data });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({ loading: false, error });
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { loading, error, data } = this.state;
        if (loading) {
            return <Layout>Loading....</Layout>;
        }

        if (error) {
            return (
                <Layout>
                    <div>
                        <p>Error:</p>
                        <code className="Code-block">{error.toString()}</code>
                    </div>
                </Layout>
            );
        }

        return (
            <Layout>
                <div>
                    <details>
                        <summary>Welcome {data.user.name}</summary>
                        <p>Here is your info: </p>
                        <code className="Code-block">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
                    </details>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is the new react hooks component that I created. As I mentioned before it's still not finished yet.

```
function LoginGoogle (props) {

    const [start, setStart] = useState(
        {
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        data: {},
           }
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/api/auth/google/callback${props.location.search}`, { headers: new Headers({ accept: 'application/json' }) })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setStart({ loading: false, data });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setStart({ loading: false, error });
                console.error(error);
            });
    })


        const { loading, error, data } = this.state;
        if (loading) {
            return <Layout>Loading....</Layout>;
        }

        if (error) {
            return (
                <Layout>
                    <div>
                        <p>Error:</p>
                        <code className="Code-block">{error.toString()}</code>
                    </div>
                </Layout>
            );
        }

        return (
            <Layout>
                <div>
                    <details>
                        <summary>Welcome {data.user.name}</summary>
                        <p>Here is your info: </p>
                        <code className="Code-block">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
                    </details>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
```

These are the steps that I took to convert the code :
[10 Steps to Convert React Class Component to React Functional Component with Hooks](https://medium.com/@olinations/10-steps-to-convert-a-react-class-component-to-a-functional-component-with-hooks-ab198e0fa139)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, the logic from componentDidMount should be within the useEffect hook, which you got it right. However, you will need to add an empty array as the dependency array, which will ensure that the HTTP request will be called once on mount:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/auth/google/callback${props.location.search}`, { headers: new Headers({ accept: 'application/json' }) })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
        })
        .then((data) => {
            setStart({ loading: false, data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setStart({ loading: false, error });
            console.error(error);
        });
}, []);
```

With that, you should conditionally render the JSX elements based on the your component's state, as defined by the `start` state:

```
const { data, error, loading } = start;

return (
  <>
    {error && (
       <Layout>
         <div>
           <p>Error:</p>
           <code className="Code-block">{error.toString()}</code>
           </div>
       </Layout>
    )}
    {data && (
      <Layout>
        <div>
           <details>
             <summary>Welcome {data.user.name}</summary>
             <p>Here is your info: </p>
             <code className="Code-block">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>     </details>
         </div>
      </Layout>
    )}
    {
      loading && <Layout>Loading....</Layout>
    }
  <>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now your fetch request is running on EVERY render, if you wanted to simulate `componentDidMount` behaviour, you would need to pass in an empty dependency array to the `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/auth/google/callback${props.location.search}`, { headers: new Headers({ accept: 'application/json' }) })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
        })
        .then((data) => {
            setStart({ loading: false, data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setStart({ loading: false, error });
            console.error(error);
        });
}, []) // See the empty dependency array
```

By adding an empty dependency list, it will run once.

`const { loading, error, data } = this.state`

becomes

`const {loading, error, data} = start`

Comment: What about the lines of code after the render method? How can I change it?